# Using DirectX pipeline for 2D rendering

Tags: directx, 2d, shader

I'd like to render 2D geometry using DirectX (11) and have tried to do so by creating an effects file that doesn't transform vertices at all - that is where you'd normally apply your world/view/projection matrix I just return the (untransformed) input.

This worked as expected and my quad was rendered to the surface correctly. Then I tried transforming it with a translation (in 2D) along the X-axis and got some weird perspective changes.

Googling around I see people talking about using the Orthogonal transform matrices but don't understand why - I don't want to transform general 3d data into 2d, I'd like to do an identity transform of 2d data into 2d (and perhaps 2d translate/scale too)

I get the feeling I've missed something important about the pipeline?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Are you using Direct3D or Direct2D?

Comment: Direct3D - its possible I might want to render both 2D and 3D from the same device/buffers in the future

Comment: @user2152466 why not paste your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have probably forgotten to call m.Transpose() on your transformation matrix after finishing constructing but before assigning it to the device

Answer (score 2):

The projection matrix that you are using is a perspective matrix which gives perspective. This is fine when you are working in 3D, but when you want to render 2D (for example to render a GUI) you don't want to add perspective.

Orthogonal matrix is a matrix which basically ignores perspective, so that objects in the distance are just as big as things that are close.

The difference between them can be visualized as followed if you draw a box (a cube with the top missing):

```
Perspective    vs    Orthigonal
O---------O             O---------O
|\       /|             |         |
| o-----o |             |         |
| |     | |             |         |
| o-----o |             |         |
|/       \|             |         |
O---------O             O---------O
```

So what happens in your case? Well, objects that are out of the center of your screen are naturally further away the objects that are near the center of your screen. Because of that they are drawn closer.

Example:

```
A      B      C        Point A (-5, 0, 5)
 \     |     /         Point B ( 0, 0, 5)
  \    |    /          Point C ( 5, 0, 5)
   \   |   /       
    \  |  /      
     \ | /    
      \|/
       V
```

As you can see point A and B are further away. If we would use really basic perspective (it is more complex, but it suffices as example) to calculate where each point would come on your screen then we would use the following formula:

```
Vector2 Perspective(Vector3 pos)
{
    return Vector2(pos.x, pos.y) / pos.length();
}
```

Now a orthogonal matrix would be more along the lines of the following:

```
Vector2 Orthogonal(Vector3 pos)
{
    return Vector2(pos.x, pos.y);
}
```

So when you replace your old perspective matrix with a new orthogonal matrix then you should no longer have problems with perspective.

Comment: thanks but I'm not using a perspective matrix - I'm using an identity matrix (not the DirectX Orthogonal matrices). I don't see why you'd need the orthogonal matrix over the identity matrix for 2D rendering or what the difference would be?

Comment: Try render a full screen quad who contains the points [0.9 0.9] and [-0.9 -0.9] if that gives you a quad that fills the entire screen except the outer border then you are **not** having problems with perspective but your images is just stretched. If that is the case then just simply use an orthogonal matrix whose input is equal to the inside of your window (aka the draw area). That should resolve the stretching effect.